# Popup on cocoa webview

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

I am trying to create a webview for [8track.com](http://8tracks.com/) in cocoa. But I am not able to support popup for sign up using  facebook / Google.
After reading few answers from SO, I have readhed upto following code, but it does not work.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener {
    _wwebView.mainFrameURL = [(NSURL *)[actionInformation objectForKey:WebActionOriginalURLKey] absoluteString];
    [_wwebView reload:self];

}
```

It does not redirect to the new authentication page.

---

Also I am not using a new popup window, because I am doubtful about weather authenticating in one webview window will not allow to login in other.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a simple view written in objective C or Swift and use the API that Facebook and Google provide?
For example with Facebook is very easy to implement the login flow:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#login-button